# How to assign variable value to a xml field within ajax block

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I am new to ajax. ,I have problem with adding XML data field in ajax query.

```
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "communication.cgi",

            async: true,
            cache: false,

            data: "<Message MainPageID=\"0\" pageID=\"1\" WebpageName=\"page1\" Action=\"upload\" />",

            datatype: "text",

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {   
                //TODO
            },

            success: function(data) 
            {
                //TODO
            }
        });
```

From the above data field, i need add filename as another one new field. The filename is stored in a variable like,

***var filename = $("#file_selector_upload").val();*** 
// filename depends on uploaded file name.

Now, This filename field need to add with the above said data field. how can add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would send the data as an JSON Object instead of XML like this:

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "communication.cgi",

    async: true,
    cache: false,

    data: 
    {
        'Message':
        {
            'MainPageID': 0,
            'pageID': 1,
            'WebpageName': 'page1',
            'Action': 'upload',
            'filename': $("#file_selector_upload").val()
        }
    },

    datatype: "JSON",

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {   
        //TODO
    },

    success: function(data) 
    {
        //TODO
    }
});
```

But if you want to send it as XML, why dont just manipulate the XML-String?

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "communication.cgi",

    async: true,
    cache: false,

    data: '<Message filename="'+$("#file_selector_upload").val()+'" MainPageID="0" pageID="1" WebpageName="page1" Action="upload" />',

    datatype: "text",

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {   
        //TODO
    },

    success: function(data) 
    {
        //TODO
    }
});
```

Comment: This line shows syntax error.


data: '<Message filename="'+$("#file_selector_upload").val()+'" MainPageID="0" pageID="1" WebpageName="page1" Action="upload" />',

 It must be in below mentioned format

**data: "<Message MainPageID=\"0\" pageID=\"1\" WebpageName=\"page1\" Action=\"upload\" />"**

Comment: It is "updated" every time you create this ajax request.

Comment: your welcome. Please mark this question as solved :)